# Is there a way to take associated files on a record and create chatter posts with them through workflow or process builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I'm trying to launch a Customer Community Plus community and have hit a roadblock.  I'm needing to share files that we've attached to one of our custom objects (called Sleep Study) with external users.  I'm now learning that you can only share files that are added through a chatter post externally.  Would it be possible (and how) to use Workflow or Process builder to go back through all of our old records and grab the associated files and then create a chatter post with them?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither Workflow nor Process Builder can assist you with this, as they cannot "go through old records"; you would still need the data loader or some other code to initiate the updates to begin with. Further, Workflow only has four possible actions, none of which include doing anything with Chatter. Process Builder can do stuff with Chatter, but posting files would actually require either Apex code or possibly a Flow. Your best bet if you're trying to avoid code would be to start by building an Automated Flow that can do the Chatter part, then build a Visual Flow that would query your old records and call the Automated Flow on them. After that, you could still use the Automated Flow with Process Builder to continue using whatever process you already have in place to upload those files, and they would be shared automatically. All of this would probably be a lot easier, though, if you could use Apex code.